# Flutter - how to trigger a function after the async function is completed

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Hi I would like for the addUserToFirestore() function to trigger after the code above has done being executed

```
Future<void> registerAccount(
      String email,
      String displayName,
      String password,
      void Function(FirebaseAuthException e) errorCallback) async {
    try {
      var credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      await credential.user!.updateDisplayName(displayName);

      addUserToFirestore();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      errorCallback(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: not sure I understood what you mean, `addUserToFirestore()` will already be executed after `updateDisplayName(displayName)`, as you are awaitng it

Comment: Code should word, but the code catches only one type of exception. Add this as the final catch to catch all errors: `catch(e){
    print(e);
  }`. Also add a `print('done')` before `addUserToFirestore()` to check the code flow.

Comment: @AJ989 what happens is the addUserToFirestore( ) fn is completed before the displayName is updated. Because of this when I access the displayName parameter in the above-mentioned function, the value is shown as null. Using Delay fixes the issue but that is like putting duct tape over the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

try and change your code to:

```
 await credential.user!.updateDisplayName(displayName)
   .then((_) => addUserToFirestore());
```

so that `addUserToFirestore()` will only fire after `updateDisplayName()` is complete